# checking whether a particular username or password already exists in a shared preference database

Tags: android

I am trying to create a sign up activity and I'm wondering whether I can use a shared preference database. Because of limited time, and most importantly, how to check whether a username or password already exists in that database. This is to prevent someone else from entering the matching records like all applications that require signing up. I have tried an if statement but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It is not recommended to use Shared Preferences to store usernames (if there will be many of them), you should use a database.

Answer (score 2):

To make Vucko's comment more clear, `SharedPreferences` is merely a .xml file on the user's device, which means that if the phone is rooted, anyone could access that file - you don't want this **security breach**.

Find a good tutorial and implement a `MySQL DB`(you can find free hosting online like [hostinger](http://www.hostinger.co.uk/)) for your app and connect to it via a PHP REST service. `Volley` library by Google will help you handle the `JSON` response from your service and you can use it to post the Username,Password etc to the database to store them.

Also use PHP's `BCRYPT` algorithm to encrypt the password before storing it in the DB and `password_verify()` when comparing passwords (you can read the PHP manual about `BCRYPT`).

When in need of tutorials, I recommend searching on `YouTube` as well. Sometimes there are very good tutorials there. Do the same about this matter.

**The Google Way**:

If that's not a big project or even if it is, you could go with a **Google login** without having a database at all. It's relatively easy to setup and it will probably take you less time if you are new to everything that I mentioned. I'm not sure however if you need a `Developer Account` or not (costs 25$ but you'd need it to release the app to the store anyway). When the users login successfully you could just save their `Google e-mail` address that they used for the login process and a boolean value of isLoggedIn set to true in `SharedPreferences`. The actual authentication would all happen on the `Google` servers without you doing anything but handling the result - success or failure.

**PHP BCRYPT**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

(don't use `MD5`, it's considered insecure and not recommended for password encryption by experts anymore)

**More about JSON**: [What is JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)

**Volley**: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

**Example tutorial**:
http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/12/android-php-insert-mysql-db-volley.html